# Adding rsa host key to known_hosts on mac

Tags: git, macos, github

Each time I push to github it works fine but I get an error message saying Failed to add the RSA host key to the list of known hosts. How do I add an rsa host key to the file ~/.ssh/known_hosts?

Comment: Actually what I've got is even more confusing; it says it _did_ add the host key, but then the next time I push it says it _again_.

Comment: This seems to be because GitHub keeps changing its internet address.